# Proguard giving errors after updating android studio 3.0.1 to 3.1 while making release build

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I updated Android Studio Version 3.0.1 to 3.1 After that while making release build  the proguard gives following error

```
Unmanaged thread operation #-5 (Tasks limiter_1)    5ms
Resolve files of :app:releaseRuntimeClasspath   5ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-fragment.aar (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to design.aar (com.android.support:design:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to appcompat-v7.aar (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to constraint-layout.aar (com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-fragment.aar (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-fragment.aar (com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to animated-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to animated-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to recyclerview-v7.aar (com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0)    1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0)    1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0)    1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to transition.aar (com.android.support:transition:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to loader.aar (com.android.support:loader:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to loader.aar (com.android.support:loader:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to viewpager.aar (com.android.support:viewpager:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to coordinatorlayout.aar (com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to customview.aar (com.android.support:customview:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to drawerlayout.aar (com.android.support:drawerlayout:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to slidingpanelayout.aar (com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to customview.aar (com.android.support:customview:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to customview.aar (com.android.support:customview:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to customview.aar (com.android.support:customview:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to customview.aar (com.android.support:customview:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to swiperefreshlayout.aar (com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to asynclayoutinflater.aar (com.android.support:asynclayoutinflater:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to versionedparcelable.aar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to cursoradapter.aar (com.android.support:cursoradapter:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to cursoradapter.aar (com.android.support:cursoradapter:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to cardview-v7.aar (com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to cursoradapter.aar (com.android.support:cursoradapter:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to runtime.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to viewmodel.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to documentfile.aar (com.android.support:documentfile:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to localbroadcastmanager.aar (com.android.support:localbroadcastmanager:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to print.aar (com.android.support:print:28.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to viewmodel.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to interpolator.aar (com.android.support:interpolator:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to livedata.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to livedata-core.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to interpolator.aar (com.android.support:interpolator:28.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to runtime.aar (android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to runtime.aar (android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@4749de1b to appcompat-v7.aar (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0)
```

gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "testcodes.and.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

how to solve ?

Comment: can you post your .gradle file ? and did you tried cleaning or invalidating cache ?

Comment: Does not look like errors to me.

Comment: @Umair please see updated question

Comment: @Riskhan your both gradle files are fine. As henry said it seems like a warning rather an error. Have you tried cleaning or invalidating cache and then restarting your android studio ?

Comment: @Umair Henry  Yes right.  I cleaned and invalidated cache the warning/error disappeared.  Thanks both